# Invoke multiple roles in Ansible with where condition

Tags: ansible

Is there a possibility to invoke roles depends on the when condition OR may be use Ansible handlers?

I have a below playbook which gets the current status of deployment on remote host and if and only required then perform the next steps. Below is the validation.yml from validations role (1st one to invoke) which does the validations -

```
---
 - name: Getting the status of current deployment
   stat:
     path: "{{ tomcat_symlink_path }}"
   register: p

 - set_fact:
     current_release: "{{ p.stat.lnk_target.split('/')[4] | regex_replace('^Release(.*)$', '\\1') }}"

 - debug:
     msg: "The currently deployed release is : {{ p.stat.lnk_target.split('/')[4] | regex_replace('^Release(.*)$', '\\1') }}"

 - name: Copying Application Configuration files and get the checksum
   template:
      src: "{{ item }}"
      dest: "{{config_location}}/{{ item | basename | regex_replace('.j2$', '') }}"
      mode: 0755
   with_fileglob:
    - /temp/env/*.j2
   register: config_var

 - block:
    - name: "Exit the deployment if no changes required...."
      debug:
        msg: "Target Release and currently deployed release is same OR no configuration changed required.. so Exiting the Deployment!!!!"

    - meta: end_play
   when: myvm_release_version == current_release and  config_var.changed  == false
```

Now depends on the above 2 variables. I need to invoke roles. For example -

1. if  `config_var.changed  == true` and `myvm_release_version == current_release`  then invoke only roles **stoptomcat** and **starttomcat** and exit the deployment because it is just the config change so only restart tomcat is required.
2. if only `config_var.changed  == false` and `myvm_release_version != current_release`  then continue with the playbook which will execute everything and all the roles

This may be a weird requirement but may be someone expert can throw some light on it.

Comment: What did your try to acheive your requirements and what is not working as expected ? You can add a `when` clause to a role declaration at play level or while your import/include_role at task level. This is rather correctly explained in the [roles documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-roles)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a common requirement
You can include role with when condition as simple as following..

Solution: 1

> you can not refer two of more than two task with when condition, only one task is allowed, 
>   simple hack can be include a external playbook In that conditional task.

Solution: 2

```
 Your Ansible code till "register: config_var"

- name: include conditional role 
  include_role: "{{item}}"
  when: config_var.changed == true and myvm_release_version == current_release
  with_items: 
    - "stoptomcat"
    - 'starttomcat" 
- name: block of code 
  block:
    // conditional ansible tasks
  when: config_var.changed == false and myvm_release_version != current_release
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find a solution as below using meta

```
- block:
    - name: "Doing Configuration Changes...."
      include_role:
        name: '{{ roleinputvar }}'
      loop:
       - stoptomcat
       - starttomcat
      loop_control:
        loop_var: roleinputvar
    - meta: end_play
   when: config_var.changed  == true and myvm_release_version == current_release
```

Just posting so it might help others.